# How to enable the XEP-0199 in Smack?

Tags: android, xmpp, ping, smack, asmack

I'm using aSmack. My app listens a chatroom and reacts to the messages but it never send a message. The app doesn't receive more messages if the chatroom remains in silence for a while and then a new message is sent. I researched and I think that [XEP-0199](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0199.html) is the solution here. I see that @Flow (the current Smack maintainer) [implemented it](https://community.igniterealtime.org/thread/48473) and [the issue related](https://igniterealtime.org/issues/browse/SMACK-388) was closed.

I think that I need to use [`PingProvider`](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/3.4.0/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smack/ping/provider/PingProvider.html) but I really don't know how to connect this class with the `Connection`.

How can I enable the [XEP-0199](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0199.html)? How can I use [`PingProvider`](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/3.4.0/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smack/ping/provider/PingProvider.html)?

---

Connection code:

```
smack = SmackAndroid.init(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
connection = new XMPPConnection(App.getServer());
connection.addConnectionListener(new ConnectionListener() {

    private final static String SMACK = "SMACK";

    @Override
    public void reconnectionSuccessful() {
        Log.i(SMACK , "reconnectionSuccessful");
    }

    @Override
    public void reconnectionFailed(Exception e) {
        Log.i(SMACK, "reconnectionFailed", e);
    }

    @Override
    public void reconnectingIn(int seconds) {
        Log.i(SMACK, "reconnectingIn " + seconds);
    }

    @Override
    public void connectionClosedOnError(Exception e) {
        Log.i(SMACK, "connectionClosedOnError", e);
    }

    @Override
    public void connectionClosed() {
        Log.i(SMACK, "connectionClosed");
    }
});
connection.connect();
connection.login(user, password);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I fix the problem implementing the ping response manually:

```
connection.addPacketListener(new PacketListener() {

    @Override
    public void processPacket(Packet packet) {
        connection.sendPacket(new Pong((Ping) packet));
    }
}, new PacketFilter() {

    @Override
    public boolean accept(Packet packet) {
        return packet instanceof Ping;
    }
});
```

Comment: what is pong? can You explain?

Comment: It seems that they remove the `Pong` class [in this commit](https://github.com/igniterealtime/Smack/commit/aab1dcdabee48b90b0d175fd99167afe92a28534). But now [`Ping` has a `getPong()` method](https://github.com/igniterealtime/Smack/blob/001e824fb9c1b3548991ea0185bd47f4ea03a087/smack-extensions/src/main/java/org/jivesoftware/smackx/ping/packet/Ping.java#L43-L45), you can try with that.

Comment: How can we manage when user go offline i mean how we can stop ping manager manually after button pressed ?

Comment: for receiving notification from FCM

Answer (score 6):

To prevent user from disconnecting your session

```
PingManager pm =  PingManager.getInstanceFor(MyApplication.connection) ;
    pm.setPingInterval(5) ;  // 5 sec
    pm.pingMyServer() ;
    pm.registerPingFailedListener(new PingFailedListener() {

        @Override
        public void pingFailed() {
            Log.e(TAG , "pingFailed") ;
        }
    });
```

Comment: I'd like to point out that a 5 second ping interval, if used on a mobile connection, will pretty fast drain the devices battery.

Comment: there is a big problem ,
if user became offline with out notifing openfire first , 
openfire will assume that the client got the packets
so it wont be sent again when he logged in 

e.g.
user A is online
user B sent MUC invitation to A
user A became offline before receiving the invitation without notifying openfire
user B will assume A recived the invitation , and the invitation is lost

Answer (score 1):

`XEP 0199` is not a solution, Ping is used to check weather the server is up or not. actually you will send ping to the server.

Now as fas as your problem is concerned. Show me the message stanza that you are trying to send. and also check if the chat-room is public or private. you can not send a message to a private chat room.

**Answer Updated:**

Try using this code for detecting message recieve

```
PacketFilter filter = new MessageTypeFilter(Message.Type.chat);
        Network.connection.addPacketListener(new PacketListener() {
            public void processPacket(Packet packet) {
                Message message = (Message) packet;
                if (message.getBody() != null) {
                    String fromName = StringUtils.parseBareAddress(message.getFrom());
                    Log.i("XMPPClient", "Got text [" + message.getBody() + "] from [" + fromName + "]");
                   //recieve.setText(message.getBody());
                    /*messages.add(fromName + ":");
                    messages.add(message.getBody());*/
                    // Add the incoming message to the list view
                    item = new RowItem(R.drawable.billing, message.getBody());
                    adapter = new CustomListViewAdapter(getBaseContext(),
                            R.layout.list_item, rowItems);
                    rowItems.add(item);
                    //listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                }
            }
        }, filter);
```

Comment: I don't want to send any message. I only want to receive all the messages in a long period of time. But when the chatroom is in silent for a while it seems that I lose the conection but I don't receive any event through  the `ConnectionListener`. In my tests the app is always in foreground and the screen turned on.

Comment: I just added it in my question.

Answer (score 0):

I called `PingManager.getInstanceFor` method to enable XEP-0199 support.